# How to create hash from array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Here is my array:

```
sorted_array = [["Friday", "42", 8], ["Friday", "34", 8], ["Friday", "41", 78], ["Friday", "35", 7], ["Friday", "40", 7], ["Friday", "36", 6], ["Friday", "39", 7], ["Friday", "37", 56], ["Friday", "38", 6], ["Monday", "38", 3], ["Monday", "39", 5], ["Monday", "37", 54], ["Monday", "40", 6], ["Monday", "36", 6], ["Monday", "41", 7], ["Monday", "35", 7], ["Monday", "42", 7], ["Monday", "34", 8]]
```

I need to make:

```
{ 'Friday' => [ ["42", 8], ["34", 8], ["41", 78], ["35", 7], [ "40", 7], ["36", 6], [ "39", 7], ["37", 56], [ "38", 6] ]  }
```

The same with `"Monday"`.Can someone shed a light on this?

This is how I get the data from POST:

```
{"0"=>{"Monday"=>{"34"=>8}, "Friday"=>{"34"=>8}}, "1"=>{"Monday"=>{"35"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"35"=>7}}, "2"=>{"Monday"=>{"36"=>6}, "Friday"=>{"36"=>6}}, "3"=>{"Monday"=>{"37"=>54}, "Friday"=>{"37"=>56}}, "4"=>{"Monday"=>{"38"=>3}, "Friday"=>{"38"=>6}}, "5"=>{"Monday"=>{"39"=>5}, "Friday"=>{"39"=>7}}, "6"=>{"Monday"=>{"40"=>6}, "Friday"=>{"40"=>7}}, "7"=>{"Monday"=>{"41"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"41"=>78}}, "8"=>{"Monday"=>{"42"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"42"=>8}}}
```

Then I turn it into array and sorted:

```
 hash_array = []
 specific_ranges.each do |key, value|
   value.each do |day, scores|
      scores.each do |a_score, amount|
         hash_array.push [day, a_score, amount]
      end
   end
 end
```

Sorted:

```
sorted_array = hash_array.sort_by &:first
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby MAGIC:

```
p sorted_array.group_by(&:shift) #=> {"Friday"=>[["42", 8], ["34", 8], ["41", 78], ["35", 7] ...
```

Explanation: `shift` gets the first value of the array and at the same time removes it from the array, so the group_by function produce exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. This is lovely, you cleaver cookie. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this directly to your data:

```
data = {"0"=>{"Monday"=>{"34"=>8}, "Friday"=>{"34"=>8}}, "1"=>{"Monday"=>{"35"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"35"=>7}}, "2"=>{"Monday"=>{"36"=>6}, "Friday"=>{"36"=>6}}, "3"=>{"Monday"=>{"37"=>54}, "Friday"=>{"37"=>56}}, "4"=>{"Monday"=>{"38"=>3}, "Friday"=>{"38"=>6}}, "5"=>{"Monday"=>{"39"=>5}, "Friday"=>{"39"=>7}}, "6"=>{"Monday"=>{"40"=>6}, "Friday"=>{"40"=>7}}, "7"=>{"Monday"=>{"41"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"41"=>78}}, "8"=>{"Monday"=>{"42"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"42"=>8}}}

a ||= Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }   
data.each{ |d|
  d[1].keys.each { |key|
    a[key] << d[1][key]
  }
}

a
# => {"Monday"=>[{"34"=>8}, {"35"=>7}, {"36"=>6}, {"37"=>54}, {"38"=>3}, {"39"=>5}, {"40"=>6}, {"41"=>7}, {"42"=>7}], "Friday"=>[{"34"=>8}, {"35"=>7}, {"36"=>6}, {"37"=>56}, {"38"=>6}, {"39"=>7}, {"40"=>7}, {"41"=>78}, {"42"=>8}]}
```

You can improve the result further by using [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) for array of hashes if required.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sorted_array.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map { |a| a[1..-1] }] }.to_h
 # {"Friday"=>[["42", 8], ["34", 8], ["41", 78], ["35", 7], ["40", 7], ["36", 6], ["39", 7], ["37", 56], ["38", 6]],
 #  "Monday"=>[["38", 3], ["39", 5], ["37", 54], ["40", 6], ["36", 6], ["41", 7], ["35", 7], ["42", 7], ["34", 8]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = sorted_array.group_by(&:first).each_value{|a| a.each(&:shift)}

h.select{|k, _| k == "Friday"}
#=> { 'Friday' => [ ["42", 8], ["34", 8], ["41", 78], ["35", 7], [ "40", 7], ["36", 6], [ "39", 7], ["37", 56], [ "38", 6] ]  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick solution for you. This may not be the optimal but here it is:

```
sorted_array = [["Friday", "42", 8], ["Friday", "34", 8], ["Friday", "41", 78], ["Friday", "35", 7], ["Friday", "40", 7], ["Friday", "36", 6], ["Friday", "39", 7], ["Friday", "37", 56], ["Friday", "38", 6], ["Monday", "38", 3], ["Monday", "39", 5], ["Monday", "37", 54], ["Monday", "40", 6], ["Monday", "36", 6], ["Monday", "41", 7], ["Monday", "35", 7], ["Monday", "42", 7], ["Monday", "34", 8]]

s = sorted_array.select{|x| x[0] == 'Friday'}.each{|a| a.shift}

Hash['Friday', s]
```

This will return the result as you require. But while doing it I found a limitation that the line of code:

```
s = sorted_array.select{|x| x[0] == 'Friday'}.each{|a| a.shift}
```

is running just a single time and it will return a blank array if you run it the second time consecutively. So if you use this please take care of that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard task for [`Array#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

```
sorted_array.reduce({}) { |memo, e| 
  (memo[e.first] ||= []) << e[1..-1]
  memo 
}
```

Here we fulfill the hash with the rest of every array element, using first elements as keys.

**UPD** Actually, you don’t need to reorganize your hash, everything might be done within one step:

```
h = {"0"=>{"Monday"=>{"34"=>8}, "Friday"=>{"34"=>8}}, "1"=>{"Monday"=>{"35"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"35"=>7}}, "2"=>{"Monday"=>{"36"=>6}, "Friday"=>{"36"=>6}}, "3"=>{"Monday"=>{"37"=>54}, "Friday"=>{"37"=>56}}, "4"=>{"Monday"=>{"38"=>3}, "Friday"=>{"38"=>6}}, "5"=>{"Monday"=>{"39"=>5}, "Friday"=>{"39"=>7}}, "6"=>{"Monday"=>{"40"=>6}, "Friday"=>{"40"=>7}}, "7"=>{"Monday"=>{"41"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"41"=>78}}, "8"=>{"Monday"=>{"42"=>7}, "Friday"=>{"42"=>8}}}
h.reduce({}) { |memo, k| 
  k.last.each { |k,v| (memo[k] ||= []) << v.to_a.flatten }
  memo 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two for the price of one:

**#1**

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |a,h| h.update(a.shift=>[a]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
```

**#2**

```
h = arr.group_by(&:first)
h.each { |k,v| h[k] = v.transpose[1..-1].transpose }
```